# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in ASP.NET MVC WebSite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, azure, response

I'm receiving this error(ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) on my WebSite(ASP.NET MVC) in some PCs of my clients.
In different clients(with diferent browsers) the Controller that show this error is different. 
One of them i have access and i tryed to debug with VisualStudio.

**Test in production**

[image: Chrome Inspector]

**Test locally**

Receiving the same error as production. I put some break points in Index of this controller and  BeginRequest/AuthenticateRequest of Global.asax, but in this client when i call CompanyUsersController don't pass in break points and others Controllers pass.
I tryed using Fiddler 2, the same as chrome inspector, get 0 Bytes in Response.

I spent so much time trying to found a better error message

The problem is probably on the server, I am using Azure.
This same project was already running a long time without problems.

Someone can share this same experience? And/or the solution?

Comment: I don't doubt the code but the server.  Are you using a load balancer?

Comment: (Edited)The problem is probably on the server, I am using Azure.
This same project was already running a long time without problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

Searching in machines that show the error Err_empty_response, i found a software used by Banks for safety.

This software is called in Brazil from WARSAW or GBuster.

**Solution 1:**

Remove this software.

**Solution 2:**

Another solution works without removing the software.
i have just to publish my website again with https:// certificate.

I hope this help someone.

Comment: The 2nd solution (activating SSL) worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

I received this on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 site in development on my machine.

Nothing logged, the call just fails in Chrome's network trace. Fiddler shows a HTTP 504. Strange!

After 10 minutes I realised my URL was HTTP when it should be HTTPS!

Comment: Can't believe it - HTTP/HTTPS is indeed the cause! Thanks!